# How can I see a log of an app that was not created locally only in the heroku dashboard?

Tags: logging, heroku

If I create an app locally and then add it to heruku running the command:

```
heroku apps:create my-app
```

I can access my logs easily running

```
heroku log
```

Although if I just hit create new app in the heroku dashboard I don't have an app home folder to run CLI commands against that home folder. How can I see the app's logs in that way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you already provided your credentials you can access any of your heroku app by

```
heroku logs --tail -a app_name
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try:

```
 heroku logs
```

Take a look at https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging#view-logs